# Testing mxGraph with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, mxgraph, react-testing-library

I'm using mxGraph library in React App. I need to create unit tests for components that draw graph. I'm using jest and [react testing library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro).
But this library cannot render out mxGraph's elements. Maybe because, while testing it cannot define screen resolution, and render out properly.

Is it possible to test mxGraph drawings or is there any examples or practices with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think RTL is the best tool for this kind of testing. It does not compute any graphical value like height and width of the elements or their positions.
I would suggest you use something like [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) for this kind of tests

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Gpx! But I'm want to know whether it is possible to implement the testing with RTL

Comment: It is not. The graph can't be rendered because your graph library doesn't know how much space is available on the page. RTL is not intended to test visual components

Comment: Ok, thank you! sorry for misunderstanding your answer

Comment: We now decided to use `Cypress`

Comment: It seems to be a really awesome tool))